# Add GUID to URL in 2 cases

Tags: javascript, query-string, guid

I have successfully been able to add a GUID to a URL using Javascript. 
This is my code I am using currently:

```
    <script>  
  if ((navigator.userAgent.match(/iPhone/i)) || (navigator.userAgent.match(/iPod/i)) ||(navigator.userAgent.match(/iPad/i))) {
       function S4() { 
           return (((1 + Math.random()) * 0x10000) | 0).toString(16).substring(1);  
       }
    // then to call it, plus stitch in '4' in the third group
       guid = (S4() + S4() + "-" + S4() + "-4" + S4().substr(0, 3) + "-" + S4() + "-" + S4() + S4() + S4()).toLowerCase();
    //alert(guid);
      var lc = window.location;
       if (!(/\?guid=/.test(lc))) { 
          window.location = window.location + '?guid=' + guid 
      }
    }//End if iPhone
</script>
```

**The Issue:**

Now I would like test the URL to see if it has a query string already in the URL and then if it does, append the GUID to the end of the query stringed URL.  How do I do that?

Let's say I have something like if the query stringed URL is like this:
http://mysite.com/mypage?query=http://mysite.com/myotherpage

I want to THEN add the GUID to the end of the queried URL like this:

http://mysite.com/mypage?query=http://mysite.com/myotherpage&guid=123456789153456

**Note:** You are probably asking why I am detecting the iPhone/iPod/iPad and adding a GUID to the URL. This is because of a documented and insane bug/feature in iOS 6.0+ combined with Mobile Safari that has still not been fixed with  'super caching' POST calls.  So adding a GUID forces the good ol' iToys to force a new page lookup.  Hate to hack this, but we have tried the Pragma=no-cache, Expires=0, and Cache-Control=no-cache and saw the issue was still persisting for us.  So yeh.

Comment: So what's the problem? The logic/code looks right. Maybe use `window.location.href` instead of `window.location`. Is your point that you want to change the page's URL without changing the page?

Comment: My issue is that I want to add the GUID and existing query string IF one exists.  I was able to add the GUID to the end of the URL, if no other query strings existed like http://mysite.com/mypage?guid=123456789 BUT I don't know how to do it when there is a query string as well. I want to append the GUID to an existing query string if it exists.

Comment: @Ian, oh wait, it just hit me. The test is looking at the URL to see if the guid variable exists.  So it should automatically work anyways if the URL does not have 'guid' variable in it. Is that the right assumption?  Did I just answer my own questions?

Comment: I realized I missed some corner cases anyways. I just added an answer. Not sure if you completely answered your own question, or if I really did with my answer, but let me know if helps/works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might need this logic:

```
var current = window.location.search;
var addon = "";
if (current.charAt(0) !== "?") {    // Querystring Doesn't start with "?"
    addon += "?";
} else {    // Querystring does start with "?" (and maybe more)
    addon += current;
}
if (current.indexOf("guid=") < 0) {    // Querystring Doesn't contain "guid="
    if (current.length > 1) {    // Querystring Contains more than "?_"
        addon += "&";
    }
    addon += "guid=" + guid;
    window.location.href = window.location.protocol + "//" + window.location.host + window.location.pathname + addon;
}
```

So it will check to see if the querystring starts with a "?". If it doesn't, it adds it.

If there's more than 1 character in the querystring (meaning it's more than just "?"...something like "?a"), then it adds a "&".

Finally, it adds "guid=23482934" (whatever value) as well.

So the scenarios are:

- "" - should become `?guid=12355235`
- "?" - should become `?guid=12355235`
- "?asdf=fdsa" - should become `?asdf=fdsa&guid=12355235`

Comment: I think there is something slightly wrong with your answer, when I did this the '&' replaced the query string which give a bad link, so the URL ended up like this http://mysite.com/mypage&guid=123456789.  Instead of http://mysite.com/mypage?query=mypage.aspx&guid=123546789.  It is really close though. I will try to mess with the code a bit, but if you know what the issue, please post. Thanks

Comment: @Carlos Yep, forgot that scenario, sorry about that. I just updated my answer :) Let me know if that fixes it!

Comment: that worked like a charm. Thank you so very much. I really appreciate the help. GUIDs and URL manipulation are not my strong suit. Other DOM manipulation, not so bad at, but not the URL stuff. Thanks again!

Comment: @Carlos Cool, seriously no problem. Sorry for the confusion at first :) I'm sure the code could be reordered (like the `if` statements) or something, to be "better", but if it works, that's great :)